# Problem with including python modules due to python version mismatch (3.8.5 vs 3.8.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

**Background of the problem:**

- I've used ubuntu 16.04 where I had to install python 3.8 from sources. I downloaded python 3.8.6 and make altinstall'ed it. It was working fine but there is a chance that I've screw-up something when linking/update-alternatives python3 to python 3.8 which now causes problem after ubuntu upgrade.
- I've uprgade to ubuntu 20.04 from 16.04 which comes with python 3.8.5

**The problem**

I had some issues with mismatching python versions (3.8.5 vs 3.8.6) after upgrading to 20.04 so I've removed(I can restore it) the manually installed python 3.8.6 from /usr/local/bin. It solves the problem partially. Now

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
$ which python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8
$ /usr/bin/python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Nevertheless when running vim with plugins which uses python 3.8 I see issues with loading python modules, e.g.:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 64, in <module>
    import msvcrt
```

or less verobse:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: No module named '_socket'
```

What is more in vim:

```
:py3 print( __import__( 'sys' ).version )
```

results with:

```
3.8.6 (default, Nov  2 2020, 13:09:31)  
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Which suggest problem with python3.8.6 and python3.8.5

**What I've tied:**

- sudo apt reinstall python3 python3-dev python3.8 python3.8-dev
- sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2
- The problem can be W/A by leaving python 3.8.6 in /usr/local/bin/ and temporary removing /usr/bin/python3* but this is not good and long term solution.

Appreciate any hints. Probably getting rid of manually installed python 3.8.6 will do the job but not sure it is possible. Additionally removing python3 via apt remove (to install it from scratch again) is probably not possible since I have only remote ssh access to that machine and expect some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as expected was related to python 3.8.6 (installed from sources) vs python 3.8.5 (which comes with ubuntu20.04 by default).

```
# ldd /usr/bin/vim | grep python
libpython3.8.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0 (0x00007f1ef9212000)
```

which was library installed during manual build and pointed to python 3.8.6 while all vim plugins were built with default python 3.8.5. After

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/temp-libpython3.8.so.1.0
```

used library points to:

```
ldd /usr/bin/vim | grep python
    libpython3.8.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0 (0x00007fa50896e000)
```

which solves the issue. Additionally now in vim I can see that python 3.8.5 and not 3.8.6 is used:

```
:py3 print( __import__( 'sys' ).version )
3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)  
[GCC 9.3.0]
```